# Using @media queries for different screen-sizes not working properly

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap with sass and trying to put different media queries to work. As the most threads are about css only, I am not sure where my problem lies and how to solve it properly.
The settings for min-width: 1400px are working while those for the smaller resolution are not. It seems like they are getting overriden by the other @media-query. How can I avoid this?

I am using Angular with Bootstrap4 and SASS. The bootstrap-class I am using is container-fluid. To make my website responsive for different devices I am trying to use @media-queries to make my Layout consistent for different devices.
I am/was also using the bootstrap classes "col-md..." and so on to make the layout responsive.

As SASS does not allow for brackets like {} and semicolons, I am not quite sure, if I am overriding something with my approach.

```
@import '../../sass/var'

@media (min-width: 1351px)
 .upper
   margin-left: 290px
 .welcome
   font-family: $font
   color: $white
   font-size: 30px
@media (max-width: 1350px)
 .upper
  margin-left: 100px
 .welcome
  font-family: $font
  color: $white
```

For higher resolutions it is working as expected and showing the desired results. Unfortunately, the lower resolution can not be changed by this approach.

Comment: Please share your HTML. Also, you can share your compiled CSS as well. Have you tried using your dev tools to see if something is getting overwritten or not applied at all? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have violated some indentation rules on the bottom block. Make sure to set correct indentation when nesting as you have done in top block.